# Get number of records from Crystal Report in C# code

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I have a C# Winforms application that creates some reports (in Crystal Report XI), sometimes by individual requests, sometimes in massive requests (5 or more reports).

I need to skip empty reports in some cases (not every time), so I would like to find a way to know how many lines my main query (a stored procedure) is returning (without re executing the stored procedure because it could take a lot of time)

I've tried to pass an output parameter to the stored procedure but it doesn't work, I can't find the output parameter in the `ParameterFields` property of the `CrystalReport` object in my code.

I've tried to reach the `Rows` property but I get an error:

> 'Report.Rows.Count' threw an exception of type System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException'

and I m not sure that this is the rows of the report data.

I don't care about subreport, I'd like to focus only on the main one.

Anyone could help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//Main Report    
CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument rd; //rd is a report with subreports which gets no data

    CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.Controllers.RowsetCursor rowsetCursor = null;
    rd.ReportClientDocument.RowsetController.CreateCursor(null, null, 0);
    if (rowsetCursor.IsEOF)
    {
        bResult = false; //main report contains no data
    }
```

from [SAP](https://answers.sap.com/questions/7015387/how-to-determine-if-a-report-has-data-before-expor.html).

Comment: Thank you. I missed some dll but i managed to make it. I just have a DB connexion error on the CreateCursor that à have to resolve.